# How to reduce updates in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this slider component in my react web application.

```
<InputRange
    minLabel="none"
    maxLabel="none"
    maxValue={5000}
    minValue={0}
    value={filterstate.minPay}
    onChange={value => inputChange(value)}
/>
```

This onchange event was called very often and as we can see in the [docs](https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range/blob/master/README.md)

i could use onchangecomplete event to set the state only when change completed.

```
<InputRange
    minLabel="none"
    maxLabel="none"
    maxValue={5000}
    minValue={0}
    value={filterstate.minPay}
    onChangeComplete={value => inputChange(value)}
/>
```

But it throws lots of errors.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onChange` is marked as required in `InputRange`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

```
input-range.jsx:294 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function
    at InputRange.updateValues (input-range.jsx:294)
    at InputRange.updatePositions (input-range.jsx:265)
```

Comment: can you set onChange in the component but don't do anything in the function? React just updates if the state is updated. So if you pass it an empty function it won't update.

Comment: If you can share the complete code.?

Answer (score 0):

As it say 'onChange' is required but you don't have to do anything in it. You can use like this:

```
<InputRange
    minLabel="none"
    maxLabel="none"
    maxValue={5000}
    minValue={0}
    value={filterstate.minPay}
    onChange={() => {}}
    onChangeComplete={value => inputChange(value)}
/>
```

Comment: what's the rest of inputChange() ?